# Set class generic value in constructor only

Tags: c#, .net, generics

There is any way to set the generic type (T) of class in the constructor only, but not in the declaration?

```
public class Gen<T>
{
}

public class Da
{
}

public class Program
{
    public static Gen<?> gen;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        gen = new Gen<Da>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing that, won't you loose the benefits of generics? Can you explain why you want such construct?

Comment: @SteveB, not at all. This allows you to have strongly-typed generic classes for the implementation while enabling their use in a non-generic context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, the easiest way to achieve this is to have a non-generic interface:

```
interface IGen { }
```

Then your generic class can be:

```
class Gen<T> : IGen { }
```

And the usage is:

```
IGen objectGen = new Gen<object>();
IGen intGent = new Gen<int>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but only by using a non-generic variable, such as `object`, any non-generic base-class or any interface that the generic class implements.

```
public interface Intf {
  void DoSomething();
}

public class Gen<T>: Intf {
  public void DoSomething() {
    // can use the generic stuff here
  }
}

public class Da {

}

public class Program {
    public static Intf gen;
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        gen = new Gen<Da>();
        gen.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can implement a non-generic abstract `Gen` base class which exposes common members that do not need to be generically typed. (or whatever makes sense for your design)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, yes, of course - but that is then a "non-generic variable", don't you agree?

Comment: You're right.  I just didn't read it that way, especially when your example was `object`, sorry.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, no worries, I slighly changed the wordig to be more clear. Thanks for the feedback. (But people seem to like rich's answer better anyways, for whatever reason.)